# Pandas: boolean indexing with 'item in list' syntax

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame with a column called col1.  If I want to get all rows where col1 == ‘a’, I can do that with:

```
df[df.col1 == ‘a’]
```

If I want rows where col1 is ‘a’ or ‘b’, I can do:

```
df[(df.col1 == ‘a’) | (df.col1 == ‘b’)]
```

But I’d really like to do the is something (syntactically illegal) like this:

```
df[df.col1 in [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’]]
```

Is there a proper pandas way to do that?

Here’s what I’m using instead:

```
sort_func = lambda x: x in [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’]
mask = df[‘col1’].apply(sort_func)
df[mask]
```

But… is there a better way to do this?  This is bothering me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for filtering

```
In [212]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]],
                            columns=['col1', 'col2'])


In [213]: df['col1'].isin(['a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[213]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool

In [214]: df.loc[df['col1'].isin(['a', 'b', 'c']), :]
Out[214]:
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     2
2    c     3
```