# Numpy boolean indexing if number is in list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-operations

I have the following array:

```
x = np.array([
    [2, 0],
    [5, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [8, 0],
    [6, 0]])
```

I've learned that you can use boolean operations to change selected values in a numpy array. If I want to change the value of the 2nd column to 1 for the rows where the 1st value is equal to 2, 5 or 8 I can do the following:

```
x[x[:, 0] == 2, 1] = 1
x[x[:, 0] == 5, 1] = 1
x[x[:, 0] == 8, 1] = 1
```

Which changes the output to:

```
[[2 1]
 [5 1]
 [1 0]
 [8 1]
 [6 0]]
```

If that were "normal" python code, I know I could do:

```
if value in [2, 5, 8]: ...
```

Instead of:

```
if value == 2 or value == 5 or value == 8: ...
```

Is there a shorthand to do something like this with numpy arrays?

Comment: Related / duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352280/pandas-boolean-indexing-with-item-in-list-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy's `isin` method:

```
x[np.isin(x[:, 0], [2, 5, 8]), 1] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`np.isin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) with [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
x[:,1] = np.where(np.isin(x[:,0], [2,5,8]), 1, 0)
```